# Apache <Files> and <FilesMatch> restricted scope in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, security, httpd.conf

Since this syntax is not allowed:

```
<Files /path/to/the/file.php>
  Options +ExecCGI
</Files>
```

Is there any way to restrict the scope of `<Files>` and `<FileMatch>` directives in httpd.conf
so that it DOES NOT propagate to sub-directories?

I have tried:

```
<Directory /path/to/the>
  Options -ExecCGI
  <Files file.php>
    Options +ExecCGI
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

alone and with additional rule:

```
<Directory /path/to/the/*>
  Options -ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

This, however, propagates to all directories within the path.

An example of such usage would be to disallow the ExecCGI option by default and allow it selectively to chosen files **without** the need to use of .htaccess files in each directory.

If you are going to advise using .htaccess solution please do not reply.

**EDIT:** I was explained that since 2.4 it's possible to use the DirectoryMatch and the dollar mark syntax to handle this (an example below) but **I haven't been able to make it work**.

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/path/to/the$">
  Options -ExecCGI
  <Files file.php>
    Options +ExecCGI
  </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Currently running apache 2.2 but might consider upgrading to 2.4 if there's a suitable solution.

Comment: This is a relevant bug, but I'm not much the wiser as to a solution after reading it -- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49809